# Norms and metrics: Two sides of the same coin?

Tags: reference-request, mg.metric-geometry

This is a second attempt after that my [previous post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/98029/every-metric-is-a-norm-closed) on the same subject has been closed since, I was said, "not a real question". Pas de problème ! I hope that it is now a little bit clearer than before.

---

It is apparent that metric and normed (vector) spaces have profound *structural* differences. Loosely speaking, a metric space is a "bare" set $X$ together with a function $d: X \times X \to X$ satisfying some prescribed properties, while a normed vector space is an algebraic structure $V$ along with a function $n: |V| \to |V|$ fulfilling a few other axioms (I'm using $|V|$ for the carrier of $V$): The former is called a distance, the latter a norm. But names do not always reflect the essential nature of concepts and they happen to mark differences that can be partly smoothed out provided that one can move uphill and watch the valley from the mountain peak.

In this line of thought, we can all agree, I think, that some (basic) issues, results and constructions local to the theory of metric spaces are conceptually close to (basic) issues, constructions and results local to the theory of normed (vector) spaces: This is the case, e.g., with the most usual choices of the class of morphisms to associate with the categories $\bf Met$ (metric spaces with Lipschitz maps as arrows) and $\bf Nor$ (normed spaces with bounded linear transformations as arrows) and with their "short variants"; with binary products and coproducts (and indeed with arbitrary nonempty products and coproducts if we let metrics and norms be valued in $[0,+\infty]$ rather than in $\mathbb{R}_0^+$); or even with some of the conditions required, with the notation from above, by the definition itself of $d$ and $n$ (I'm especially thinking of the triangle inequality). These similarities are all the more striking, I think, if we enlarge our scope and bring other normed structures into the picture (e.g. normed groups [1], valuated rings [2], and normed algebras): Let me refer to these, in what follows, as *normed algebraic structures* (it is not that important, I think, to know what it is formally meant by a *normed algebraic structure*). One is then naturally prompted to raise the question: Does there exist some higher perspective (say, some sort of abstract theoretical framework, hopelessly shaped on the language of categories), where algebraic normed structures are all special instances of one same archetypical structure? But this is not my question. Instead, my question is

> whether or not anything similar has been already done in the literature in relation to the construction of a unified framework where metric spaces AND algebraic normed structures can be all regarded as instances of the one same archetypical structure.

Here, the term "structure" must be formally intended as "model of a finitary first-order theory (in one or many sorts) interpreted over $\bf Set$ or another category $\bf C$ with some appropriate properties" (the underlying formal language, say, is that of the NBG class theory).

**Notes.**
[1] See, e.g., N.H. Bingham and A.J. Ostaszewski, Normed groups: dichotomy and duality, CDAM Research Report Series, LSE-CDAM-2008-10, London School of Economics, 2008 and references therein.
[2] I'm using the term "valuation" as a synonymous of "absolute value".

Comment: Things with norms have a distinguished point, namely the element of norm zero

Comment: No, I don't agree. It would be more correct to say that _some_ things with norms have a distinguished point, namely the element of norm zero.

Comment: I think the English idiom you're looking for is 'two sides of the same coin'.

Comment: Name me an example of something that is commonly called a normed algebraic structure which does not possess a distinguished point, namely the unique element of norm zero.

Comment: A linear normed space is naturally a metric space. Metric spaces are a much wider class. In fact, up to isometries, they are all subsets of metric spaces. That said, I can't really see how one could see norms and metrics as "to sides of the same coin"

Comment: I also vote to close this instance of the question. I do not understand what you are looking for. For a metric one has some sort of distance and  for a norm some sort of size that typically can be turned into a distance by considering the size of the difference (cf also Yemon's comment). And now you have been told twice that you can 'realize' any metric space as some subset of a normed space. This seems enough of an answer to me. 

Comment: @Yemon. Nah, wait! First, "Common things with norms" is not the same as "Things with norms": this is cheating! :) Second, you know much better than me that, in the search of a unified view pointing to glue together ideas so far from each other (at least apparently), one has to separate what is "essential" from what is rather "accidental". Based on this, I could actually reply your question with another question: Why on earth should "things with norms" be _inherently_ characterized by the property of having one distinguished element with norm zero? Lawvere's work on generalized metrics... (tbc)

Comment: ...contains, among the other marvelous insights, the key observation that symmetry is not an essential property of metrics. Today in hindsight, it may sound trivial. But, given that Lawvere's research grew up on the path carved out by a somewhat consolidated tradition, let me say that it was indeed a small Copernican revolution. Yes, I could actually reply that, but I won't. Instead, I will invite you to consider that normed semigroups, in spite of the fact that, for some apparent reasons, very few people have studied them, are an example of algebraic normed structures for which... (tbc)

Comment: ...it is not true that we have a distinguished element with norm zero.

@Pietro. I don't know what you mean by saying that "A linear normed space is _naturally_ a metric space." Well, I know that, for $(V, \|\cdot\|)$ a normed space over a given valuated field $(\mathbb K, |\cdot|)$, the map $d: |V| \times |V| \to \mathbb{R}_0^+: (x,y) \mapsto \|x-y\|$ is a metric on $|V|$ (the carrier of $V$). What I don't really understand is why $d$ is pretended to be _natural_ (which is, in fact, part of another question that I'd like to raise). That said, one of many possible follow ups... (tbc)

Comment: It is not really clear what the question wants. Norms are convex functions, not all metrics are convex, so while these things are related, they are different, and this difference is what makes things interesting. Norms and metrics share a "subadditivity" behavior that unites them---but from a computational point of view, the distinction based on convexity can be extremely important (think NP-Hard vs. polynomial time).

Comment: ...to your closing comment may be: With a little effort of imagination, as for everything else. :) @quid. There are a lot of things that I can't understand. Yet, this doesn't mean at all that something is meaningless as I cannot understand it. Can you point out what is wrong with this new version of my question? I'm not asking about the possibility of embedding a metric space into a normed one: there is no reference, either implicit or explicit, to the word "embedding" in the OP. So why do you persist on this point? 

Comment: If you want to ask about "metrics" which do not assume symmetry, then why not ask about them? I really do not understand this Procrustean urge to try and subsume metric objects under normed objects. Norms measure size, metrics measure distance. (Invoking NCG at this point will, I'm afraid, not improve my mood.)

Comment: @Suvrit. The question is: Do you know of any previous attempt to put metric spaces and normed structures within one same abstract framework, in such a way that the former and the latter are definitely recovered as specializations of one same abstract notion of "structure"? What I mean by "structure" is explained at the end of the OP: _The term "structure" must be formally intended as "model of a finitary first-order theory (in one or many sorts) interpreted over Set or another category C with some appropriate properties" [...]._

Comment: Meta thread: http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/1368/are-the-norms-and-metrics-as-parts-of-some-whole-questions-appropriate/

Comment: Moreover, I disagree with the fact that "norms" have to be convex functions. Yes, of course, they are convex if you focus on the case of normed (vector) spaces. But convexity doesn't happen to be a property, e.g., of group norms and ring valuations. @Yemon. Why do we look for unifying views in mathematics? And, above all, what is NCG?!?

Comment: @Salvo Tringali: If every metric space 'is' a subset of a normed (vector) space and conversely every subset of a normed (vector) space is a metric space, then perhaps we found a unifiying structure?!

Comment: @quid. I don't think so, since a structure, as you can read in the OP (and I've been repeating since the very beginning), must be intended as a "model of a finitary first-order theory interpreted over $\bf Set$ or another category $\bf C$ with appropriate properties." Though we can embed a metric space into a normed one (by the Kuratowski embedding theorem), the embedding is not sending a metric space into a $\bf Set$-model of the first-order theory of real normed spaces. Isn't clear that any possible unification of the two concepts (that of metric and the one of norm) cannot depend... (tbc) 

Comment: ...on any result which is local to the (classical) theory of either metric or normed (vector) spaces? 

Comment: @Salvo Tringali: I think this archetypical structure is just the structure of transitive $G$-space, endowed with a $G$-invariant metric. The invariance implies that the metric is determined by the distances from any selected point of the $G$-space, which can be called the origin of the space.